# Compare the Current Record to Previous Record and group them based on some conditions

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have the below Dataset

```
Date    | status       |
20230101| C            |
20230101| C            |
20230101| F            |
20230101| C            |
20230101| C            |
20230101| F            |
20230101| C            |
20230101| F            |
20230101| F            |
```

I need to perform the grouping in such a way that each status record is compared to it's previous status record, they are not in the same group as long as the Current Record  is C & Previous Record is F

the output should be

```
Date    | status       | id
20230101| C            |1
20230101| C            |1
20230101| F            |1
20230101| C            |2
20230101| C            |2
20230101| F            |2
20230101| C            |3
20230101| F            |3
20230101| F            |3
```

```
 Dataset<Row> ds =  dataset
            .withColumn("newVal", when(col("status").equalTo("C"), 1).otherwise(0))
            .withColumn("id", expr("row_number() over (order by Date)"))
            .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

I don't think this is working , can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.withColumn("prev_status", lag($"status", 1).over(Window.orderBy($"i")))
  .withColumn("next_group", when($"status" === "C" && coalesce($"prev_status", lit("F")) === "F", 1))
  .withColumn("id", sum($"next_group").over(Window.orderBy($"i")))
```

But note that you need something to order by. Date column in your example is not unique - it doesn't guarantee any order and Spark could mix rows when shuffling. I replaced `Date` by `i` in my query, hopefully you have some column to use here.